# Onclick day close bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to close datepicker when click on day. How is this possible in Bootstrap Datepicker?

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kGGCZ/17/

```
$('#dob').datepicker(
{
    endDate:ageDate
}
);
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You the auto-close property of the bootstrap date-piker like below

```
$('#dob').datepicker(
{
    endDate:ageDate,
    autoclose: true
}
);
```

I have already updated your js-fiddle

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kGGCZ/18/)

Answer (score 6):

Note that if you are using Stefan Petre's [original version of the Bootstrap Datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/), the autoclose property will [as of this writing] not work. In this case, you should do something like this:

```
$('#myDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (e) {
    $('#myDate').datepicker('hide');
});
```

If you're using eternicode's [forked version](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker), the autoclose property will work.

Answer (score 4):

initialize your date picker with option 'autoclose'

```
$('#dob').datepicker(
{"autoclose": true});
```

or you can close date picker by using following code also

```
$('#dob').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    $('#dob').hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Date3').datepicker({
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        viewMode: "months",
        minViewMode: "months"
    }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
        $('#Date3').datepicker('hide');
    });
```

Comment: could you please add more details with your code. thanks